# Eclipse, move src output folder to WEB-INF/classes

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have folder structure like this

```
SampleWeb/
         src/main/
                  java : All java classes <br/>
                  resources : All properties file etc<br/>
                  webapp : WEB-INF folder and other jsp pages
         pom.xml
```

Now, default eclipse build creating target folder and moving all output files to target folder as like

```
target/classes/
              all .class files (of src folder)
              all properties (of resource folder)
              jsp files (of webapp folder, and ofcourse WEB-INF folder too)
```

So what I am looking for is, how can move all .class files to WEB-INF/classes folder dynamically using eclipse build.

Comment: You say "using eclipse build", but your project layout appears to be a Maven project.  Are you sure you're not using m2e or any other Maven plug-in for Eclipse?

Comment: Looks like this is a maven build. Well, for Maven, `target/classes/` is the default location where it copies the o/p classes. You can use a post build action (eg. maven copy task) to move the classes elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

What is really in a name: `src` contains sources. The same goes for `src/main/webapp/` and `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`. It should not contain build artifacts (such as class files).

When using Maven, all build artifacts go into `${project.build.directory}`, in other words: `target/`.

Your desire to have class files end up in `scr/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` sounds as if you want a directory to run your web application from. Instead of moving class files (source files!) into `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` (more source files!) you should move both of them somewhere else, typically below `target/`.

There is a host of plugins that can do that for you, depending on your exact desires. There is the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) for a variety of *advanced* assembly tasks, there are simpler plugins that offer copy functions, and there's plugins dedicated to assembling web applications ([WAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)) or running them from Maven ([Tomcat plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/)).

These allow you to do anything such as WARs, unpacked WARs, skinny WARs, etc.

Using `m2e` you can have this taken care of in the background while editing in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can take my example as a reference.
I used to output all test files into the classes-folder, so they can be compiled and packaged together.
Here's the code snippet.

```
<!-- define the output directory of test files -->
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```